# rtl direction for a Lightning data table in vertical view

Tags: lightning, css, lightning-design-system, datatable

I am new to **lightning design system**.

I am using a responsive `data table` for both directions:

- lrt
- rtl

The **horizontal** **table** is working perfectly fine in both **direction**.

But in the **vertical** table view, **rtl** direction is **not** working. The vertical table is automatically comes based on **view**(responsive table).

I am trying to find documentation for this, but not getting any clue or help from the documentation.

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th scope="col" ng-repeat='val in data' ng-hide='!val.isDisp'>
                <div class="slds-truncate">{{::val}}</div>
            </th>
            <th width="70px"/>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='slds-block_table-body'>
        <tr name="form">
            <td ng-style="{'padding':'0px'}">
                <span class="icon-save"></span>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat='row in details'>
               {{::row}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please suggest how it can achieve for the **vertical** view.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: @MartinLezer, I have added code. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the Lightning Design System doesn't support RTL out of the box: https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/308

At Vlocity we've added support, but it's not been merged in to SLDS as there have been questions and concerns about different approaches. For example see this PR for 2.2.x https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/pull/438

However you can use our branch which is currently aligned with SLDS 2.2.3 (we're a little behind the latest): https://github.com/vlocityinc/design-system/tree/mgoldspink_Salesforce/master

To make this work, you need to sync up the branch and build the code as per the standard build docs for SLDS. This will generate additional .rtl.css files. In our visualforce pages we detect that language of the User using:

```
public static Boolean isLanguageRTL() {
    String language = UserInfo.getLanguage();
    if (language == 'iw' ||
        language == 'ar' ||
        language == 'ur') {
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then in our VF pages we add the following logic to include the right stylesheet:

```
      <apex:stylesheet value="{!IF(isLanguageRTL, URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.rtl.min.css'), URLFOR($Resource.slds, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css'))}"/>
```

Then the final missing piece is that  element needs the slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal class:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal">
```